# Does DataView.RowFilter support 'between ... and ...'?

Tags: .net, expression, dataview, rowfilter, datacolumn

I am to change a program to filter datum based on a range of values.

Though this is not efficient, the information is loaded in memory for the specified period of time and filtered based on some criterion for separate treatment, be it the production of a CSV report.

The information is loaded up into a [**`DataView`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx), which shall then be filtered depending on the operation being processed. Each three processes process a subset of this `DataView`. The subset is then determined by a filter through the [**`DataView.RowFilter`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) property.

Based on what I found so far, the [**`DataColumn.Expression`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) applicable to the `RowFilter` seems to take fully advantage of a SQL `where` clause syntax as follows.

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Id = 999";
dataView.RowFilter = "Name like 'Stack%'"
dataView.RowFilter = "Id in (1, 2, 3, 10, 16, 34)"
dataView.RowFilter = "Amount < 5000"
```

As stated in this post: [**DataView RowFilter Syntax [C#]**](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/).

Now I wonder, being in presence of legacy uneasy-to-test code, whether the `DataView.RowFilter` property supports the SQL [**`between`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) condition?

**Would this be a valid `DataColumn.Expression` to apply as a `DataView.RowFilter`?**

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Name = 'StackOverflow' and Amount between 5000 and 5999";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i remember correctly `Between` is not supported, but why not simply:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Name = 'StackOverflow' and Amount >= 5000 and Amount <= 5999";
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.90).aspx): mentions `Between` only as reeserved word but it is not supported in the expression.

I have tested it and using `BETWEEN` throws an `EvaluateException`:

> {"The expression contains unsupported operator 'Between'."}

Here is the test-code, sample-data:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add("Site1", 1000);
table.Rows.Add("OtherSite", 3000);
table.Rows.Add("StackOverflow", 5100);
table.Rows.Add("StackOverflow", 5500);
table.Rows.Add("StackExchange", 5900);

var dataView = table.DefaultView;
```

First, valid expression using `AND`:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Name = 'StackOverflow' and Amount >= 5000 and Amount <= 5999";

Console.Write("Count: {0}\r\nValues:\r\n{1}"
    , dataView.Count
    , string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dataView.Cast<DataRowView>() 
        .Select(o => string.Join(",", o.Row.ItemArray))));
```

Output:

```
Count: 2
Values:
StackOverflow,5100
StackOverflow,5500
```

Now the invalid syntax using `BETWEEN`:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Name = 'StackOverflow' and Amount BETWEEN 5000 and 5999"; // boom
```

Comment: "Why not simply [...]?", simply because I would have preferred to use the `between` statement as it makes it more obvious that it is a range a single field. I finally ended up using the `and` comparison as suggested. =)